# in golang, reflect pkg, 8g error "undefined: reflect.NewValue"

Tags: reflection, go

little confused with reflect pkg

all of the examples us `reflect.NewValue()` to get the `reflect.Value` of a var, but

- `func NewValue` is not documented in http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/
- the 8g compiler returns "undefined: reflect.NewValue"

is `NewValue()` still supported? if not, how does one get `reflect.Value` from a var?

---

the Typeof and NewValue functions have been renamed to TypeOf and ValueOf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Go [reflect package](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) was substantially revised for the [weekly.2011-04-13](http://golang.org/doc/devel/weekly.html#2011-04-13) and subsequent releases. For details, see [revision 843855f3c026](http://code.google.com/p/go/source/detail?r=843855f3c026).

Comment: ok!  quote: Also, the Typeof and NewValue functions have been renamed to TypeOf and ValueOf.